# Xcode signal SIGABRT

Tags: xcode, sigabrt

I received this warning from Xcode, though I have not changed a single character in the appdelegates (I´m new to Xcode). Nothing seems to work.

Here is the line it breaks:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([Tre01AppDelegate class]));
```

I´ve changed the document version, restarted Xcode, the iOS simulator and the computer.

The problem I was working on while this error popped up, was embedding a webView, which I embedded in a new view controller (then I added the .h and .m-files for this controller, and set up the code for loading a website...). It all looked good and connected then the above came up.

Why is the appdelegate important to my web view, which is located in another viewcontroller? Do I have to initialize the new viewcontroller in the app delegate?

Many thanks, I know – I´m not very specific in adressing the problem, but I´m quite new to Xcode...

Comment: What error message do you get in debug view with this SIGABRT ?

Comment: I hope i got the right lines:   2013-06-14 15:02:49.395 Tresiba[1512:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[WebViewController01 _setViewDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x758b7e0'

libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: then here it is : your `WebViewController01` class doesn't implement `_setWebViewDelegate:`

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. Although i really don´t know what to do now :(

Comment: look for `_setWebViewDelegate:` in your code, then look to `WebViewController01` class properties/method to find the correct method name responsible to set this 'web view delegate' , and replace the wrong method name by the good one... This kind of problem cannot be detected by compiler when method is called through `@selector(methodName)` (which implies the actual method is dynamically resolved at runtime, and - if not found - could be responsible for the error you're seeing)

Comment: searched for _setWebViewDelegate: and didn´t find it in any file... and that may be the problem. Damn. I don´t get it. I think i´ve structured the whole thing wrong. But again – thank you!

Comment: Are you using XIBs or Storyboard ? XCode search doesn't look into these files.

Comment: Storyboard, and it worked fine to this point (custom menus, two levels deep), but when i added the new view controller and within it the webview, it crashed. EDIT: And yes, it must be at runtime, cause the simulation works until i press the button which sends the app to the viewcontroller with the webview.

Comment: Since i´m not allowed to post pics directly, here is a pic of the storyboard...   http://www.5crows.net/xcodecrash01.png

Comment: some property, or IBOutlet defined in your storyboard is wrong... My hint : select the 'webView01 scene' , and check connection inspector for yellow/warning signs...

Comment: Hey, thanks again. There is no yellow warning. I´ll try to build it again from scratch.